# Titan server configuration for windows server 2008

Tags: titan

io-strategy is set as "worker" in titan-server-rexter.xml config file (default installation) 
Second session's Gremlin queries does not work with it.

I've set io-strategy as "leader-follower". It seems working. Is this configuration appropriate for production environment?

Why second gremlin queries are not working (hanging) with "worker" configuration?

Storage layer is BerkeleyDB.
Client is: RexProClient (C#) The issue is not related with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use leader-follower.  I believe there are issues with "worker" that might be related to bugs in grizzly (but that hasn't been completely proven).  The leader-follower strategy on the other hand is being used in a number of production environments that I know of.  Be sure to increase the size of the thread-pools in rexster.xml when you install to a production environment.  You may wish to follow this thread for more information as it develops:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gremlin-users/wmvNi6hZWT8